# how much resource reserved on a mesos-slave

Tags: mesos

How does mesos-slave calculate its available resources. In web-ui, mesos-master shows 2.9G memory available on a slave, but I run "free -m":

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3953       2391       1562          0       1158        771
-/+ buffers/cache:        461       3491
Swap:         4095         43       4052
```

and --resource parameter was not given.
I want to know how does mesos scheduler calculate resources available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that calculates available resources that are offered by slaves can be seen [here](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/slave/containerizer/containerizer.cpp#L61-L160), in particular, the memory part is [lines 98 to 114](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/slave/containerizer/containerizer.cpp#L98-L114).

If the machine has more than 2GB of RAM Mesos will offer `total - Gigabytes(1)`. In your case the machine has ~4GB, and that's why you're seeing ~3GB in the Web UI.